# vertical scrollbar inside JQuery Popup window

Tags: php, jquery, scrollbar

I am following 
http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/ tutorial on how to make a jQuery pop up window.
when i click on the button , it will display a pop up window with tweets from a particular hashtag , any idea on how to add a vertical scrollbar so that the pop up window will be within the screen 
Any idea on how to add a scrollbar?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

on the container div add `overflow-y:scroll` to the styles.

Also make sure your tweet's are display:block. If they're floated, insert a clear div under the markup e.g. `<div style="clear:both;"></div>`. That will push down the height.

Answer (score 0):

it is because of unmanageable height use `overflow: auto`
that will adjust the height of div container means your popup